# Subreport order sorting

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports, subreport

In my report there are currently 2 subreports, let's call them *A* and *B*.
The *A* lists Cash positions, and the *B* lists Stocks.
I run this report from a web based *Java* environment, the *JasperReports*'s report reads from a sql database.

I want to pass an argument to the *JR* report that tells it in what order to arrange the subreports, in this case for e.g. (*B* first, then *A* or  vice versa).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send a parameter of boolean type. while generating report. on the basis of that parameter you should define the path of subreport.
Here is jrxml code for subrepor path.e.g.

For first subreport:

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="8dba7f58-0466-4504-9d51-7484786450d2" positionType="Float" x="0" y="16" width="315" height="16"/>              
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfObject})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{swap} == true ? "/path/to/first/subreport" : /path/to/second/subreport]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

And for second subreport:

```
<subreport>
        <reportElement uuid="8dba7f58-0466-4504-9d51-7484786450d2" positionType="Float" x="0" y="16" width="315" height="16"/>              
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfObject})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{swap} == true ? "/path/to/second/subreport" : /path/to/first/subreport]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```

And vice-versa in other case.I have not tested. Please have a look.

Enjoy.

Comment: Now to move away from the example towards reality - there is an X amount of subreports (so let's say I have 10 of them - Cash, Stocks, Futures, etc.) so the argument that comes from the DB is not only the order of the subreports but also which ones to display. - So the data could be B,D,A (run report 2, then 4, then 1 ..leave out the rest). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If you have more than 2 subreport and you want to manage them according to your choice then you should use dynamic jasper.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more complex subreportExpression and "Print When Expression".
In first subreport set print when to something like

```
$P{NUM_OF_SUBS} <= 1 ? true : false
```

in second

```
$P{NUM_OF_SUBS} <= 2 ? true : false
```

etc...
And for subreportExpression in first subreport something like:

```
$P{SUBS}.split(",")[1] == "A" 
    ? "repo:subA.jrxml"
    : $P{SUBS}.split(",")[1] == "B"
      ? "repo:subB.jrxml"
      : $P{SUBS}.split(",")[1] == "C"
        ? "repo:subC.jrxml"
        : "repo:subD.jrxml"
```

and in second:

```
$P{SUBS}.split(",")[2] == "A" 
    ? "repo:subA.jrxml"
    : $P{SUBS}.split(",")[2] == "B"
      ? "repo:subB.jrxml"
      : $P{SUBS}.split(",")[2] == "C"
        ? "repo:subC.jrxml"
        : "repo:subD.jrxml"
```

etc...

Comment: thanks. I clearly see this pointing to having just one subreport that would loop through the array and each time do the check and call the subreport (as many times as there are values in the array. is that possible?

Comment: If you put subReport element in details band it will render for each row read from data source. And you can use fields instead of parameters to determine which subReport to show. That's what I use...

Comment: Yes true. but it does not loop through the array.

Comment: because the data looks as follows: client1, data1, data2, data3, client2, data1, data2 - the subreport should loop through the array telling it which data to populate first, then second, then third

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that in a Jasper report, maybe subReport in a subReport?